# Resolving IPv6 requsets on IPv4 VPS

Tags: ipv6, centos-6, ipv4, vps

I have a VPS(Virtual Private Server) from `hetzner.com` with Centos-6.9

The VPS can only work with `IPv4` and the server don't support IPv6.

Now i setup and running a proxy on this VPS(shadowsocks). When client request IPv6 address the VPS can not resolve the address. in `/var/log/messages` appears messages like these:

```
May 29 10:19:17  /usr/local/bin/ss-server[1483]: connect to [2a03:2880:f216:c4:face:b00c:0:43fe]:443
May 29 10:19:17 /usr/local/bin/ss-server[1483]: connect: Network is unreachable

May 29 10:22:04 /usr/local/bin/ss-server[1483]: failed to lookup v6 address DNS server returned answer with no data

/usr/local/bin/ss-server[1910]: failed to lookup v6 address DNS server returned answer with no data
```

Question: Is there any way to resolving or handle the `IPv6` requsets on my VPS that don't support `IPv4`?

Answer (score 1):

Well... logically, if you don't have IPv6 support, then you cannot access IPv6 addresses. That's what "IPv6 support" *means.*

However, your server *can* have IPv6 support. Hetzner provide a /64 subnet [for every server](https://wiki.hetzner.de/index.php/Zusaetzliche_IP-Adressen/en); all you need is to configure it in your OS.

In places where the network itself isn't IPv6-capable (or your reseller is pretending that it isn't), use a tunnel (VPN) through another server – or a public tunnel provider such as Hurricane Electric's Tunnelbroker. These take a minute to set up.

Comment: I asked from VPS supporter, and they told IPv6 don't provided!
Unfortunately My VPS provider is a Hetzner seller.

Comment: So it's not _actually_ from hetzner.com but from some other company that's reselling Hetzner's services with fewer features...what's the point in that? You can use a third-party tunnel provider in this case.

Comment: ip lookup demonstrate location is in Germany, Hetzner!!!
Reseller is possible.
`third-party tunnel` like?

Comment: Tunnelbroker is popular in Europe.